# OPERATOR_BRACKET_IS_NOT_SUPPORTED on boost::bimap

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bimap

I am trying to use the bracket operator on a `boost::bimap` but without success.

For the problem I seek to solve I need a `bimap` that fulfills the following requirement:

- **left**  sorted, unique `int`
- **right** non unique, non sorted type

This lead me to choose the following `typedef` for my `bimap`,

```
typedef bimap<int, multiset_of<int> > bm;
```

I want to use the bracket operator on this type but without success. This is the code that I use,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bimap/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/multiset_of.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::bimaps;

int main()
{
    typedef bimap<int, multiset_of<int> > bm;
    bm mapping;

    mapping.insert(bm::value_type(1, 1));
    mapping.insert(bm::value_type(2, 1));
    mapping.insert(bm::value_type(3, 4));

    for (auto it : {1 , 2, 3})
        mapping.left[it] = it;

    for (auto it : mapping.left)
        cout << "{ " << it.first << ", " << it.second << " }  ";    

   return 0;
}
```

This gives me a long compile error where the essential bit seems to be

```
/usr/include/boost/bimap/detail/map_view_base.hpp:351:9: error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed'
        BOOST_BIMAP_STATIC_ERROR( OPERATOR_BRACKET_IS_NOT_SUPPORTED, (Derived));
```

(full live live example and compiler output can be found on: [rextester](http://rextester.com/IAHUQ71973))

I tried the solution below but it still yields errors,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bimap/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/multiset_of.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::bimaps;

int main()
{
    typedef bimap<int, multiset_of<int> > bm;
    typedef bm::left_map map_type;
    bm mapping;

    map_type& m = mapping.left;

    mapping.insert(bm::value_type(1, 1));
    mapping.insert(bm::value_type(2, 1));
    mapping.insert(bm::value_type(3, 4));

   for (auto it : {1 , 2, 3})
       m[it] = it;

    for (auto it : mapping.left)
        cout << "{ " << it.first << ", " << it.second << " }  ";    

   return 0;
}
```

How can I declare a `bimap` that fulfills my requirements and supports the bracket operator?

Comment: I clarified my question. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, we refer to [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/differences_with_standard_maps.html):

> set_of and unordered_set_of map views overload operator[] to retrieve the associated data of a given key only when the other collection type is a mutable one. In these cases it works in the same way as the standard.

You are using a non-mutable type on the right-hand-side:

> ```
> Side collection type       Dereferenced data
> --------------------------------------------
> set_of                     constant
> multiset_of                constant
> unordered_set_of           constant
> unordered_multiset_of      constant
> list_of                    mutable
> vector_of                  mutable
> unconstrained_set_of       mutable
> ```

So, you cannot use `operator[]`.

The error message says as much:

```
OPERATOR_BRACKET_IS_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. How can I declare the bimap such that the right hand side because mutable?

Comment: @Stereo: I listed the mutable views. I recommend abandoning the dream of `operator[]` and just using the supported APIs for the types you're using.